# What is the correct way to dealing with each chunk data in a chunked response using reactor-netty?

Tags: reactor-netty

I am working with an API server implements a "server-push" feature by using an infinite chunked response. Each chunk in the response represents an message server pushed to client. Each chunk is actually a complete json object. Here is the code I am using as a client receiving the messages server pushed to.

```
Flux<JSONObject> jsonObjectFlux = client
        .post(uriBuilder.expand("/data/long_poll").toString(), request -> {
          String pollingRequest = createPollingRequest();
          return request
              .failOnClientError(false)
              .failOnServerError(false)
              .addHeader("Authorization", host.getToken())
              .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
              .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH,
                  String.valueOf(ByteBufUtil.utf8Bytes(pollingRequest)))
              .sendString(Mono.just(pollingRequest));
        }).flatMapMany(response -> response.receiveContent().map(httpContent -> {
          ByteBuf byteBuf = httpContent.content();
          String source = new String(ByteBufUtil.getBytes(byteBuf), Charsets.UTF_8);
          return new JSONObject(source);
        }));
    jsonObjectFlux.subscribe(jsonObject -> {
      logger.debug("JSON: {}", jsonObject);
    });
```

However I got exception like:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 846 [character 847 line 1]
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 846 [character 847 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:260)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:360)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:214)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:363)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:214)
```

Obviously, I am not getting a whole json data. I am wondering if using `response.receiveContent()` is the right way to deal with one chunk data.